# OpenTok ObjC: Subscriber cannot here Publisher audio unless Publisher Subscribes to audio

Tags: objective-c, audio, opentok

So at seemingly random times, when a subscriber joins a Publisher's video chat (or vice versa), the audio from the Publisher will not be heard by the subscriber.  This happens on random occasions and cannot pin point the issue.

The only way I have publisher audio to be heard by the subscriber 100% of the time is that I have the Publisher subscribe to their own audio, which produces a slightly annoying echo.

The Publisher can hear the subscriber audio no problem with no echo on the subscribers end.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have no idea why this would happen. Are both endpoints on iOS? Are you using real devices or the simulator?

Comment: @AdamUllman Yes, both points are iOS. Real devices (iPhone 6 Plus, iPhone 5, iPad mini 4) since video does not work in the simulator.  It happens on 10.3 and 11.0.  Tried on all device and iOS combinations I have. 10.3 to 11.0, 10.3 to 10.3, 11.0 to 11.0.